# C++ SHA256 is different from command line SHA256

Tags: c++, hash, openssl, sha, sha256

I'm trying to compute a SHA256 hash of the string `iEk21fuwZApXlz93750dmW22pw389dPwOkm198sOkJEn37DjqZ32lpRu76xmw288xSQ9`

When I run my C++ code, I get a string that's not even a valid SHA256 hash. However, when I run `echo -n iEk21fuwZApXlz93750dmW22pw389dPwOkm198sOkJEn37DjqZ32lpRu76xmw288xSQ9 | openssl sha256`, I get the correct hash. Here's my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

std::string hash256(std::string string) {
    unsigned char digest[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    SHA256_CTX ctx;
    SHA256_Init(&ctx);
    SHA256_Update(&ctx, string.c_str(), std::strlen(string.c_str()));
    SHA256_Final(digest, &ctx);

    char mdString[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*2+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        std::sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);

    return std::string(mdString);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *hash = hash256("iEk21fuwZApXlz93750dmW22pw389dPwOkm198sOkJEn37DjqZ32lpRu76xmw288xSQ9").c_str();
    std::cout << hash << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Another thing to note: When I run my code in an online compiler, such as [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), I get the correct hash. I am compiling with G++ on Cygwin with OpenSSL version `OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014`

Comment: This code works for me on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: @Csq Yeah, that's very strange.

Comment: You're not null terminating `mdString` - although since you know its length you could use that to construct your string result anyway. Also calling `strlen` on the contents of a `std::string` is very odd; there is a `length()` member that works much better.

Comment: In `main` you should declare `hash` as `std::string`, or you end up with a dangling pointer to the contents of a destroyed string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Alan Stokes, you have Undefined Behavior due to a dangling reference to the internal structure of the string.  Change your declaration of `hash` in main:

```
std::string hash = hash256("...");
```